# Nuget package in Xamarin.Forms project is installed but get missing reference

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, reference, nuget-package

I'm working on a multiplatform project with Xamarin.Forms in Visual Studio 16.9.2.
With the solution Nuget packages manager I installed the [SharpFluids](https://github.com/MadsKirkFoged/SharpFluids) package and got no errors or warning.

Now, I can find SharpFluids and other dependecies in the projects dependencies, and also I can see the dlls that Sharpfluids should wrap ([CoolProp](https://github.com/CoolProp/CoolProp)).

Unfortunately the `using SharpFluids` directive doesn't work. I get the CS0246 error, namespace not found.

What am I missing?

Comment: do you have any reason to believe this will work in Xamarin?

Comment: well, I'm not sure about it, but, if not, I was expecting some sort of error during the installation of the package, or a warning about the incompatibility of the dll with Xamarin. I'm not a pro and when I read there were no particular dependency on the Nuget package description, I thought it would work.
So, am I wrong?

Comment: I checked the package in NuGet. It does not support Xamarin. https://www.nuget.org/packages/SharpFluids/2.0.89?_src=template

Comment: Thank you for the check @WendyZang-MSFT. Can I ask you how you did it, so I learn to do it by myself?

Comment: You could check the Dependencies of this package on GitHub. If the Dependencies support xamarin, this package support Xamarin as well.